# Laravel changing the inner join via user input

Tags: sql, laravel

My Plan is the following. 
I have this inner join:

```
SELECT cd.fk_lend_id,cd.serialnumber ,customers.name,cd.created_at
FROM cd
INNER JOIN customers ON cd.fk_lend_id = customer.lend_id
Where cd.fk_lend_id = 00000000;
```

This is what it would look like in Laravel:

```
$scores = DB::table('cd')
->join('cd', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer.lend_id')
->select('cd.fk_lend_id','cd.serialnumber','users.name', 'cd.created_at')
->where('cd.fk_lend_id',00000000)
->get();
```

(The created_at stands for the time the customer lend the cd)

->where('cd.fk_lend_id',00000000) <- The zero´s should be replaced with the user input from the inputfield from the view and after the input it should be redirected is this possible?

If it is possible does anyone can give me advice how to do so?

(Edit)

The "yourcds" function:

```
public function yourcds(Request $request, cds $cd)
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

    $user_input = $request->userInput
    $scores = DB::table('cd')
    ->join('customers', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer .lend_id')
    ->select('cd.fk_lend_id','cd.serialnumber','users.name', 'cd.created_at')
    ->where('cd.fk_lend_id',$request->$user_input)
    ->get();

    $cds = cd::latest()->paginate(20);

    return view('cd.yourcds',compact('cd'))
        -> with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 20);
}
```

The "return" function:

```
    public function return(cds $cd)
{

  return view('cd.return',compact('cd'));
}
```

Comment: `00000000`, replace this with `$request->inputFieldName`, and you may redirect https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects

Comment: Without quotation marks?

Comment: yes, no need of quotation marks around `$request->inputFieldName`, because it is variable

Comment: better show your full code in controller, so that we can help exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to get user input with

```
$user_input = $request->userInput
```

Then, just put in your where clause

```
$scores = DB::table('cd')
        ->join('cd', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer.lend_id')
        ->select('cd.fk_lend_id','cd.serialnumber','users.name', 'cd.created_at')
        ->where('cd.fk_lend_id', $userInput)
->get();
```

That's it, no quotation marks needed

**EDIT**

with your function return the view with form:

```
public function return(cds $cd) {
    return view('cd.return',compact('cd'));
}
```

Define route to yourcds() method:

```
Route::post('/yourcds', 'ControllerName@youcds');
```

In cd.return file place form like this

```
<form action="/yourcds"  method="POST"> 
    @csrf 

    <input type="text" name="userInput" >

    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

In your method yourcds() palce parameter Requsest:

```
public function yourcds(Request $request) {
    $this->middleware('guest');

    $user_input = $request->userInput
    $scores = DB::table('cd')
    ->join('customers', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer .lend_id')
    ->select('cd.fk_lend_id','cd.serialnumber','users.name', 'cd.created_at')
    ->where('cd.fk_lend_id',$request->$user_input)
    ->get();

    $cds = cd::latest()->paginate(20);

    return view('cd.yourcds',compact('cd'))
        -> with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 20);
}
```

Hope that's the answer

Comment: I have one blade called "return.blade.php" there happens the user input this user input should get inserted into the inner join to form the tabel on my other blade called "yourcds.blade.php" so i have a function called yourcds and a function return. In the return function is just a return view.. And in the yourcds function stands the inner join etc. So how did i get this user input from return to yourcds and what stands in the "$request" when i insert this where the inner join stands i get a undefined variable error

Comment: It will be good if you post your code fragment. you must pass `Request $request` parameter in your function and then get request input with `$request->userInput`

Comment: I have edited my post thanks for your effort. Now you can see both functions return and yourcds.

Comment: See my Updated answer and tell me if it helps

Comment: I get this error:  Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message

Comment: look inside routes if you have post method on route where you are posting form

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the

```
->join('cd', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer.lend_id')
```

Should be

```
->join('customers', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer.lend_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function <controller-name>(Request $request){
$myfield = $request->input('<formfieldname>');
$scores = DB::table('cd')
->join('cd', 'cd.fk_lend_id', '=', 'customer.lend_id')
->select('cd.fk_lend_id','cd.serialnumber','users.name', 'cd.created_at')
->where('cd.fk_lend_id',$myfield)
->get();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I will keep that in mind but what do you mean with "$request" ? I changed it to request()->input

Comment: The function declaration of a controller  is of the form:- function <controller-name>(Request $request,$id)...$id is for url parameter...$request is used to extract form data...Note Assuming POST method...

Comment: i have edited my post. i want to paste the user input from the view "return" to the inner join which stands in the controller in the function yourcds. After the user inputs the data and the data is tranfered into the inner join he should be redirected to the site yourcds.